# Unity script not working becasue it continues idk why

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CardMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 position1;
    Vector3 position2;
    Vector3 position3;
    Vector3 position4;
    Vector3 position5;
    Vector3 position6;
    bool pos1 = false;
    bool pos2 = false;
    bool pos3 = false;
    bool pos4 = false;
    bool pos5 = false;
    bool pos6 = false;
    Vector2 cardPos;
    public cardtestcontrols cardcontrols;
    string cardTest;

    public float objectSpeed;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        position1 = new Vector2(-4.0f, -2.0f);
        position2 = new Vector2(-2.0f, -2.0f);
        position3 = new Vector2(0.0f, -2.0f);
        position4 = new Vector2(2.0f, -2.0f);
        position5 = new Vector2(4.0f, -2.0f);
        position6 = new Vector2(6.0f, -2.0f);
        cardTest = cardcontrols.cardtest;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MoveGameObject(cardTest);
    }

    void ChoosePos()
    {
        if (pos1 == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("pos1");
            cardPos = position1;
            pos1 = true;
            return;
        }
        else {
            if (pos2 == false)
            {
                Debug.Log("pos2");
                cardPos = position2;
                pos2 = true;
                return;
            }
            else {
                if (pos3 == false)
                {
                    Debug.Log("pos3");
                    cardPos = position3;
                    pos3 = true;
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    if (pos4 == false)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("pos4");
                        cardPos = position4;
                        pos4 = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (pos5 == false)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("pos5");
                            cardPos = position5;
                            pos5 = true;
                            return;
                        }
                        else {
                            if (pos6 == false) {
                                Debug.Log("pos6");
                                cardPos = position6;
                                pos6 = true;
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        
    }
```

for some reason when i run this it continues down the chain but i want it to stop when it finds one that is false, i tried adding return; to the end of them as you can see but it isn't working what do you guys think????...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................i added the dots cause my post was mostly code but theres not much else to say

Comment: Have you ever heard of `if else`? There is no need to have so many nesting levels .. then I don't see what `MoveGameObject` does exactly but if this is called in `Update` it might just end up with calling `ChoosePos` each frame which would simply bubble through the 6 cases one per frame ... what exactly are you trying to achieve? I would in general rather use an array of positions and a simple index for going through them

Answer (score -1):

Change all the `if` statements apart from the first one to `else if` and remove all the `else` statements like this

```
void ChoosePos()
{
    if (pos1 == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("pos1");
        cardPos = position1;
        pos1 = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (pos2 == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("pos2");
        cardPos = position2;
        pos2 = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (pos3 == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("pos3");
        cardPos = position3;
        pos3 = true;
        return;
    }
            
    else if (pos4 == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("pos4");
        cardPos = position4;
        pos4 = true;
        return;
    }
               
    else if (pos5 == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("pos5");
        cardPos = position5;
        pos5 = true;
        return;
    }
    else if (pos6 == false)
    {
        Debug.Log("pos6");
        cardPos = position6;
        pos6 = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I said in my comment yes .. doesn't make much of a difference logic wise though .. it is just cleaner, yes ... those `return` statements make the `else` redundant also btw .. I would still rather go with an array ... and still if you call this repeatedly which is probably the main issue then it will still continue to bubble through the positions one per frame